# Use 'Oath Token' in Azure Devops Yaml file not working

Tags: oauth, azure-devops, yaml

We are using Azure Devops and want to use the variable "$(Rev:r)" in the update assembly task.
However we get build errors when using the this variable.

Yaml task:

```
  - task: update-assembly-info@2
    displayName: 'Update Assembly ...........'
    inputs:
      assemblyInfoFiles: ...........
      company: '...........'
      product: ...........
      copyright: '© $(Assembly.Company) $(Date:yyyy)'
      fileVersionMajor: '$(Date:yyyy)'
      fileVersionMinor: '$(Date:MM)'
      fileVersionBuild: '$(Date:dd)'
      fileVersionRevision: '$(Rev:r)'
      assemblyVersionMajor: '$(Date:yyyy)'
      assemblyVersionMinor: '$(Date:MM)'
      assemblyVersionBuild: '$(Date:dd)'
      assemblyVersionRevision: '$(Rev:r)'
```

However we get the following error:

```
##[error]'Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token' must be enabled when using the $(Rev:r) variable
```

When we do the exact same steps without using a yaml file but in the GUI in Azure Devops, we can enable the "*Allow scripts to access the OAuth token*" property and is is working as expected.[image]

How can we enable this OAuth token in the yaml file? So we can use this "$(Rev:r)" in the update assembly task in the yaml file?

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own issue with a workaround.

I use the $(rev:.r) in my build name and use an powershell task to extract the rev-number to a variable.

Complete yaml code for this workaround:

```
name: $(date:yyyyMMdd)$(rev:.r) #buildnumber format

  - task: InlinePowershell@1                
    displayName: 'Powershell to get the "RevisionNumber"'
    inputs:
      Script: |
        $BuildNumberParts = $($env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER) -split '\.';
        $RevisionNumber = [int]$BuildNumberParts[$BuildNumberParts.Length-1] ;
        Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=RevisionNumber]$RevisionNumber";

  - task: update-assembly-info@2
      displayName: 'Update Assembly ...........'
      inputs:
        assemblyInfoFiles: ...........
        company: '...........'
        product: ...........
        copyright: '© $(Assembly.Company) $(Date:yyyy)'
        fileVersionMajor: '$(Date:yyyy)'
        fileVersionMinor: '$(Date:MM)'
        fileVersionBuild: '$(Date:dd)'
        fileVersionRevision: '$(RevisionNumber)'
        assemblyVersionMajor: '$(Date:yyyy)'
        assemblyVersionMinor: '$(Date:MM)'
        assemblyVersionBuild: '$(Date:dd)'
        assemblyVersionRevision: '$(RevisionNumber)'
```

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to dont create a ps1 only for this, if you set the BuildNumber as the revision number, it will be increased automatically.

this works fine:

```
name: $(Rev:r)

  - task: update-assembly-info@2    
    inputs:     
      assemblyInfoFiles: '**\*AssemblyInfo.*'
      company: 'Wolters Kluwer España, S.A.'
      product: 'a3Innuva | Nomina'
      fileVersionMajor: '$(majorVersion)'
      fileVersionMinor: '$(minorVersion)'
      fileVersionBuild: '$(releaseVersion)'
      fileVersionRevision: '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
      assemblyVersionMajor: '$(majorVersion)'
      assemblyVersionMinor: '$(minorVersion)'
      assemblyVersionBuild: '$(releaseVersion)'
      assemblyVersionRevision:  '$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally it should be done like this

```yaml
- task: update-assembly-info@2
  inputs:
    assemblyInfoFiles: '**\*AssemblyInfo.*'
  env:
    SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN: $(System.AccessToken)
```

However, this is **the issue with the task itself which doesn't support properly mapping** `System.AccessToken`. There is an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/BoolBySigma/UpdateAssemblyInfo/issues/33)

Comment: Tried both ways but still getting the "##[error]'Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token' must be enabled when using the $(Rev:r) variable" error

Comment: Strange. This is taken from here https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/1827 so maybe this is specific to this task

Comment: Indeed a problem with this task --> https://github.com/BoolBySigma/UpdateAssemblyInfo/issues/33

Comment: @StephanVanDenHoogen Can you consider marking my reply as answer and upvoting it? I think that we can't do much here, and it would be good to mark this question as solved since we are helpless.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you used the following task:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bool.update-assembly-info&targetId=6fb42553-7924-4488-975a-69568174ecbe

You can see this task has been stopped updating since 6/11/2017, and there is no `Environment Variables` option in this task. To overcome this problem we can use the [counter function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#counter) instead of `$(Rev:r)`. Check the following example:

```
variables:
  major: 1
  minor: $[counter(variables['major'], 1)]

steps:

- task: update-assembly-info@2
  inputs:
    assemblyInfoFiles: '**\*AssemblyInfo.*'
    company: 'com'
    product: 'pro'
    fileVersionMajor: '$(Date:yyyy)'
    fileVersionMinor: '$(Date:MM)'
    fileVersionBuild: '$(Date:dd)'
    fileVersionRevision: '$(minor)'
    assemblyVersionMajor: '$(Date:yyyy)'
    assemblyVersionMinor: '$(Date:MM)'
    assemblyVersionBuild: '$(Date:dd)'
    assemblyVersionRevision: '$(minor)'
```